# MailJet: A template language occurred when sending a message using Template [ID]

Tags: html, json, for-loop, object, mailjet

While testing a **MailJet** email template with a simple custom html code block. The received test email throws an error. (Live preview in browser works fine)

From *templating-language-error@mailjet.com*:

> A template language occurred when sending a message using Template [ID]: expression parsing error ## Unknown identifier: object.field1 ## near ## {{ object.field1 ##

The following code is used inside the html block:

```html
{% for object in var:objects %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ object.field1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.field2 }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.field3 }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.field4 }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The following data is used for testing:

```js
{
  "Data": {},
  "Variables": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "field1": "field1 value 1",
        "field2": "field2 value 1",
        "field3": "field3 value 1",
        "field4": "field4 value 1"
      },
      {
        "field1": "field1 value 2",
        "field2": "field2 value 2",
        "field3": "field3 value 2",
        "field4": "field4 value 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this. Help is welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope, still on the todo list :/

Comment: Okay. I just open a ticket at mailjet support. Hope then can help me.

Comment: Great, keep us updated!

Comment: More than one year has passed and the issue is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Try changing it to:

```
{% for object in var:objects %}
  <td>{{ object.field1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.field2 }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.field3 }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.field4 }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem for me was in the text-mode editor. Because by default the setting 'Autogenerate plain text version' is on, but the text version doesn't support the for loop.

So, when the text version was auto generated, the for loop has been removed but the variables, like in your example `{{ object.field1 }}` stayed. And that was causing the error.

Comment: And what did you do with the for loop?

Comment: Just removed it as its not supported in the plain text version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces after and before of the variable name:

now:
{{ object.field1 }}

expected:
{{object.field1}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).